# How to find latitude and longitude using C#

Tags: c#, rest, google-maps, latitude-longitude

I have a `WCF` service in C#.

In the Service call client sends a city name. I want to convert the city name to latitudes and longitudes and store in Database under demographics.

I am planning to use Google API to implement above functionality.

I have obtained an API key from Google and its of type 'Service account'.

How can I obtain the latitude and longitude using which APIs?

Do I need to install some `SDK` or any `REST` Service will do?

Comment: All the answers reference google maps; if you are open to using bing maps, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/geocoding

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want to use the Google Maps API have a look at their REST API, you don't need to install a Google Maps API just send a Request like

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true_or_false
```

and you will get a response XML.

For response JSON:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Estância+Sergipe,&key=**YOUR_API_KEY**
```

For more Information have a look at

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/index#GeocodingRequests

Comment: If you want JSON then you can use http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=false

Comment: Amazing and so much helpfull

Answer (score 67):

You could try the NuGet package [GoogleMaps.LocationServices](http://nuget.org/packages/GoogleMaps.LocationServices), or just spin of its [source code](https://github.com/sethwebster/GoogleMaps.LocationServices). It uses Google's REST API to get lat/long for a given address and vice versa, without the need for an API key.

You use it like this:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var address = "Stavanger, Norway";

    var locationService = new GoogleLocationService();
    var point = locationService.GetLatLongFromAddress(address);

    var latitude = point.Latitude;
    var longitude = point.Longitude;

    // Save lat/long values to DB...
}
```

Comment: Is there any limit on this? In first answer Google clearly said can not use legally except google maps and has some specified limit on number of requests.

Comment: The same limit as the answer above applies to this. It's only a C# wrapper around the REST API. See [the source code](https://github.com/sethwebster/GoogleMaps.LocationServices/blob/master/GoogleMaps.LocationServices/GoogleLocationService.cs#L14)

Comment: This saved me hours of parsing XML. +1, this is an elegant solution!!

Comment: NuGet took a little tinkering, but once I installed the NuGet Extension, and added the reference to the project (having to browse to the installed package) this worked beautifully.  Thanks!

Comment: @khellang nice code, good example, a problem my apps work not work motive key .snk a error `Error 1 Assembly generation failed -- Referenced assembly 'GoogleMaps.LocationServices' does not have a strong name xxxxxxxPlugins\CSC PluginsMAPA` ... thanks a code!

Comment: @KingRider If you need a strong-named version, I suggest you try out [StrongNamer](https://github.com/dsplaisted/strongnamer)

Comment: Made my life easier

Comment: "without the need for an API key" yet it tells me I am not authorisized

Comment: If you hit the limits, you need an API key. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/33427519/682105

Answer (score 7):

You can pass address in particular url.. and you get latitude and longitude in return value dt(datatable)

```
string url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=" + address+ "&sensor=false";
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);

using (WebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    DataTable dtCoordinates = new DataTable();

    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        DataSet dsResult = new DataSet();
        dsResult.ReadXml(reader);
        dtCoordinates.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[4] { new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)),
                    new DataColumn("Address", typeof(string)),
                    new DataColumn("Latitude",typeof(string)),
                    new DataColumn("Longitude",typeof(string)) });
        foreach (DataRow row in dsResult.Tables["result"].Rows)
        {
            string geometry_id = dsResult.Tables["geometry"].Select("result_id = " + row["result_id"].ToString())[0]["geometry_id"].ToString();
            DataRow location = dsResult.Tables["location"].Select("geometry_id = " + geometry_id)[0];
            dtCoordinates.Rows.Add(row["result_id"], row["formatted_address"], location["lat"], location["lng"]);
        }
    }
    return dtCoordinates;
}
```

Comment: i used this but i need <location_type>ROOFTOP</location_type> ,but didn't find the location_type in dsresult?

Comment: Ok I will check.

Answer (score 6):

```
     /*Ready to use code :  simple copy paste GetLatLong*/
    public class AddressComponent
    {
        public string long_name { get; set; }
        public string short_name { get; set; }
        public List<string> types { get; set; }
    }

    public class Northeast
    {
        public double lat { get; set; }
        public double lng { get; set; }
    }

    public class Southwest
    {
        public double lat { get; set; }
        public double lng { get; set; }
    }

    public class Bounds
    {
        public Northeast northeast { get; set; }
        public Southwest southwest { get; set; }
    }

    public class Location
    {
        public double lat { get; set; }
        public double lng { get; set; }
    }

    public class Northeast2
    {
        public double lat { get; set; }
        public double lng { get; set; }
    }

    public class Southwest2
    {
        public double lat { get; set; }
        public double lng { get; set; }
    }

    public class Viewport
    {
        public Northeast2 northeast { get; set; }
        public Southwest2 southwest { get; set; }
    }

    public class Geometry
    {
        public Bounds bounds { get; set; }
        public Location location { get; set; }
        public string location_type { get; set; }
        public Viewport viewport { get; set; }
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public List<AddressComponent> address_components { get; set; }
        public string formatted_address { get; set; }
        public Geometry geometry { get; set; }
        public string place_id { get; set; }
        public List<string> types { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<Result> results { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
    }


    public static RootObject GetLatLongByAddress(string address)
    {
        var root = new RootObject();

        var url =
            string.Format(
                "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={0}&sensor=true_or_false", address);
        var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        var res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

        using (var streamreader=new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamreader.ReadToEnd();

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result))
            {
                root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(result);
            }
        }
        return root;


    }


          /* Call This*/

var destination_latLong = GetLatLongByAddress(um.RouteDestination);

var lattitude =Convert.ToString( destination_latLong.results[0].geometry.location.lat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

 var longitude=Convert.ToString( destination_latLong.results[0].geometry.location.lng, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: In my case, Google map gives result for the address, and this method gives null value for lat/long result, what could be the issue?

Comment: Use this API for Reverse Geocoding.: http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=false

Comment: Nope, I want to get the lat/long from address string.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Google are [OpenStreetMap's Nominatim APIs](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/).

Unlike Google they don't have a daily limit as long as you aren't making an excessively intensive use of them (more than 1 request per second). Below code works for Blazor Server.

```
    [Inject] IJSRuntime _js { get; set; }

    public async Task<Coordinates> GetCoordinates(string city) {
        Coordinates coordinates = new Coordinates();
        string query= String.Format("https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q={0}&format=jsonv2", city);
        string result = GetRequest(query); //returns a stringified array of js objects
        IJSObjectReference objArray= await _js.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("JSON.parse", result); //parse the string to a js array
        IJSObjectReference obj = await objArray.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("shift"); //take the first element in the array
        string jsonResult = await _js.InvokeAsync<string>("JSON.stringify", obj);
        dynamic dynamicResult = JObject.Parse(jsonResult);
        coordinates.Latitude= dynamicResult.lat;
        coordinates.Longitude= dynamicResult.lon;
        return coordinates;

    }

    public string GetRequest(string url) {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
        request.UserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36";
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }

    public class Coordinates {
        public double Longitude { get; set; }
        public double Latitude { get; set; }
    }
```