# Get latitude and longitude of address in Asp.net?

Tags: google-maps, asp.net-mvc-4, latitude-longitude

How can I get a latitude and longitude of some location in asp.net MVC4?

For example how can I get the latitude and longitude of Hafeez center, Lahore, Punjab, Pakistan?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# - How to find latitude and longitude using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354867/c-sharp-how-to-find-latitude-and-longitude-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the google [GeoCoding service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) to convert an address to a set of coordinates.

For example for your address you would call:

[http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Hafeez+center,Lahore,Punjab,Pakistan&sensor=false](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Hafeez%20center,Lahore,Punjab,Pakistan&sensor=false)

My recommendation would be to do something like:

```
var responseDocument = XDocument.Load("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Hafeez+center,Lahore,Punjab,Pakistan&sensor=false");
```

Then read the xml to the information you need.

Edited to add - make sure you **check google's terms and conditions**, they prohibit some types of applications!

Comment: Great - I was trying to figure this out myself the other day, if you're happy can you mark it as the answer?