# Why am I getting "Unable to read data from the transport connection"

Tags: c#, google-maps, geolocation, latitude-longitude

I have few address(~100) in my database. I want to retrieve the latitude and longitude information of all the address.
I referred to answer of [khellang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354867/c-sharp-how-to-find-latitude-and-longitude-using-c-sharp/14355156#14355156) to get the latitude and longitude of an address.
I am getting the latitude and longitude of a single address at single run.
But I am getting exception as "**System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection was closed.**" when I use the for loop to get the latitude and longitude of addresses one by one.
What could be the reason behind this.
I am making a C# Console Application for this. Should it be web application or web service application. Is the reason behind the error is using console application.
I am just a dummy beginner on this.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. I simply changed the line :

```
var locationService = new GoogleLocationService();
```

to

```
var locationService = new GoogleLocationService(true); //use Https
```