# Why does the Google Geocoding API work without key?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm reading the documentation for the Google Geocoding API, and I noticed that it [says](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) that a key is required in a geocoding request, but when I do "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=LosAngeles,usa" it gives me the expected result.

Why is this? Is the documentation wrong? Will it start asking for the key after a certain amount of requests? Or is there something I'm not understanding?

Comment: no they will work without key also but till a limit after that you need to pay and api keys are use d to monitor your usages.

Comment: So if I'm sure my application will never reach the limit I shouldn't care about the key, right?

Comment: yes................at least till they makes it necessary.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Providing a key is not required for most geocoding API requests. When you do not provide a key, Google will use an IP-based quota to determine when you reach the 2,500-queries daily limit.

Some parameters **require** a key and will not allow IP-based quota. These are explicitly marked in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) with:

> **Note:** This parameter is available only for requests that include an API key or a client ID.

Currently, this is only for two parameters in reverse geocoding: `result_type` and `location_type`.

Comment: Are you certain its IP based?  I have an app that I am using without a key.  I test on a phone connected to my computer - the phone has no carrier thus its only enabled via wifi.  During testing I occasionally see the quota hit, when that happens I then load the app on a phone with t-mobile or verizon service...connect it to my computer, wifi off..and I still the get the quota error message.  This implies its not IP based and that they are tracking my app package ID or something.  I originally read it was IP based too but now I don't think that is 100% accurate.

Answer (score 10):

[source](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/user-guide/?__utma=102347093.1234358392.1485178307.1525620926.1525620926.1&__utmb=102347093.0.10.1525620926&__utmc=102347093&__utmx=-&__utmz=102347093.1525620926.1.1.utmcsr=google%7Cutmccn=(organic)%7Cutmcmd=organic%7Cutmctr=(not%20provided)&__utmv=-&__utmk=191062186&_ga=2.176534117.1130731548.1525620899-1234358392.1485178307)

> Beginning on June 11, 2018, you’ll need to enable billing with a
>   credit card and have a valid API key for all projects. This will give
>   you the ability to scale easily with less downtime and fewer
>   performance issues. In addition, we’re simplifying our 18 individual
>   APIs into three products: Maps, Routes, and Places.
>
> Also, in June 2016 we announced that we would stop supporting keyless
>   usage, meaning any request that doesn’t include an API key or Client
>   ID. This will go into effect on June 11th, and keyless access will no
>   longer be supported. At that time, keyless calls to the Maps
>   JavaScript API and Street View API will return low-resolution maps
>   watermarked with “for development purposes only.” Keyless calls to any
>   of the following APIs will return an error: Maps Static API (including
>   Static Street View), Directions API, Distance Matrix API, Geocoding
>   API, Geolocation API, Places API, Roads API, and Time Zone API.
>
> To avoid a service interruption to your projects, please visit our Get
>   Started page to enable a billing account and generate an API key. Once
>   you generate and secure an API key, make sure to update your
>   application with the new API key.